# Nginx config for vue app + php symfony backend

Tags: php, nginx, server, backend, devops

I would like to run symfony app in subdirectory like example.com/api. What is wrong with my config? I recieve 404 without other errors

```
server {
       listen 80;
       listen [::]:80;

       server_name www.example.com example.com; 

        location /api {
                alias /var/www/dev/symfony-server/public/;
                try_files $uri index.php$is_args$args;
                fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php7.3-fpm.sock;
                fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.*)$;
                include fastcgi_params;
                fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $realpath_root$fastcgi_script_name;
                fastcgi_param DOCUMENT_ROOT $realpath_root;
                internal;
        }
}
```

Comment: What is your problem? Are you getting errors? Can you show us any errors? What are you expecting to see? What are you seeing? Your question is not complete at all.

Comment: @killstreet sorry I updated my post. I receive only 404 without error logs

Comment: You haven't set a root directory for nginx to look for your files

Comment: I specified alias.

Answer (score 0):

You are missing your root directory for your nginx to look into.

Try something like the following:

```
server {
    listen 127.0.0.1:80;
    server_name dev.blog.local blog.local www.blog.local;
    root /Volumes/git/blog/public;
    location / {
        # try to serve file directly, fallback to index.php
        try_files $uri /index.php$is_args$args;
    }

    location ~ ^/(index)\.php(/|$) {
        fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.*)$;
        include fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $realpath_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        fastcgi_param DOCUMENT_ROOT $realpath_root;
    }
    location ~ \.php$ {
        return 404;
    }
}
```

Comment: where you specify '/api/ path here?

Comment: It is an example not a full answer. You can modify this to your own requirements.

Comment: you really think I did not try it? :D but I solved a problem. The problem was that if you have an alias and php app under some directory, $fastcgi_script_name path is not valid, you have to set it manually